# date and time query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select all the records that has the same month with the current month.

```
 $date=date('Y-m-d');

    $month=substr($date,5,2);


    $res=mysql_query("SELECT DATE FROM reports");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

    $months=substr($row['DATE'],5,2);

}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sql let handle that for you like this

```
$query = "SELECT DATE FROM reports WHERE MONTH(DATE) = ".date("m");
```

in case you want only everything of that month *this year* then the query would look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE FROM reports WHERE YEAR(DATE) = ".date("Y")." MONTH(DATE) = ".date("m");
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know there was a feature like this in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
$query = 'SELECT DATE FROM reports WHERE MONTH(DATE) = MONTH(CURDATE())';
```

?

Comment: You're right. Using curdate is nicer than date("m"), +1 from me